# How to set limit in consuming message from google Pub/Sub?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I just want to consume 1000 messages per minute from google pub/sup in my spring boot application. Is there a way to set it like this in spring boot application? I searched many websites but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: you can achieve via setting concurrency at individual Message listener, please do let me know what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you have only 1 consumer, it should be possible. If you have several consumers, you can't.